# tomcat7-maven-plugin: run multiple webapps but port 8080 already in use

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, tomcat7, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm trying to use `tomcat7-maven-plugin` to setup an embedded tomcat container, run webapps in `pre-integration-test` phase, run integration tests, then shutdown tomcat in `post-integration-test` phase. The project is a multi-module maven project (contains `app1`, `app2`, etc). Parent `pom.xml` looks like following,

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <contextFile>path/to/context.xml</contextFile>
        <tomcatUsers>path/to/tomcat-users.xml</tomcatUsers>
        <fork>true</fork>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>tomcat-run</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>shutdown</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I just run `mvn clean integration-test --projects=app1,app2`. **When the second app is starting**, I get `java.net.BindException`,

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1091)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 34 more
```

So is there a configuration in `tomcat7-maven-plugin` to run multiple webapps in an embedded tomcat?

Comment: Are you sure the port 8080 was not binded before? I suggest to ensure it using netstat. Is it possible to run the single application?

Comment: if you're on linux this will give you the process ID which occupies port <PORT>:  sudo netstat -tulpn | grep <PORT>.

Comment: @Michael Yes port 8080 was not binded. Single app started fine. The problem I think is that `app1` started fine in an embedded tomcat and took port 8080. Then `app2` tried to start in another embedded tomcat. Probably this is how `tomcat7:run` works. If I use `tomcat7:run-war`, the plugin will run wars of of `app1` and `app2` altogether?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [tomcat7:run](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) mojo parameters: you can configure plugin executions to use other ports, with something similar to this config:

```
<execution>
    <id>tomcat-run</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

And of course use another port for the second project.

Comment: Did you mean specifying `port` config in parent `pom.xml`? How do I do this with multiple modules?

Comment: I mean specifying in each module (not the parent) a specific port. You can keep the same configuration in the parent, and just add the specific configuration to the modules.

Answer (score 0):

It should be supported. You should configure the webapps element in the configuration and Tomcat will deploy all applications:
http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Look also [How to use maven plugin tomcat7:run with multiple contexts (WARs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959975/how-to-use-maven-plugin-tomcat7run-with-multiple-contexts-wars)