# Run two maven modules using mvn tomcat7:run

Tags: maven, tomcat

I've got the following project layout:

```
web_root
- pom.xml -> packaging: pom
- web_relay
     - pom.xml -> packaging: war
     - src/...
- web_service
     - pom.xml -> packaging: war
     - src/...
```

My `web_root`'s `pom.xml` has is the superproject and contains two `modules`: `web_relay` and `web_service`.

For reasons unknown someone split these projects rather arbitrarily. I've been trying to merge these projects under one maven superproject.

I can run each of the `web_relay` and `web_service` projects using `mvn tomcat7:run`. However, I need both running on the same tomcat server. When I run `tomcat7:run` on `web_root`, however, it only runs the tomcat server for one of the two modules.

How can I get `mvn tomcat7:run` to run both wars?

---

The approach from [How to use maven plugin tomcat7:run with multiple contexts (WARs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959975/how-to-use-maven-plugin-tomcat7run-with-multiple-contexts-wars) works only if I `mvn install` my dependencies separately and don't include them as `modules`. If I do include them as `modules`, mvn will just run `tomcat7:run` in the first module it finds.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959975/how-to-use-maven-plugin-tomcat7run-with-multiple-contexts-wars

Comment: @Zarathustra I tried that, but that gets me into new issues.

Answer (score 0):

Run the war's from a dummy module, listing all dependencies as 'webapps'.

I.e. in the individual pom's, use:

```
<build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
```

And make a new module that launches all dependencies at once

```
<build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webapps>
                       <webapp> 
                         <groupId>com.company</groupId> 
                         <artifactId>webapp-1</artifactId> 
                         <version>1.0</version> 
                         <type>war</type>    
                       </webapp> 
                       [Add more]
                    </webapps>
```

As an alternative, and maybe a better solution in the long run, package all web applications in a single EAR (enterprise archive: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/), so you can also deploy them in production in a single action.

Tomcat7 does not support EAR deploys, but TomEE does: http://tomee.apache.org/maven/run-mojo.html
And JBoss, too: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html

Comment: So for `n` webapps I need an `n`-deep maven dependency graph? Seems like a bit of a waste. This answers the 'possible duplicate' question, but doesn't show how I can do this in a project with submodules...

Comment: Why do you have multiple war submodules? Are you re-inventing the EAR?
Why can't you make a single war with multiple controllers/servlets?

Comment: I didn't make the projects, and the person who did kind of made a mess of it. However I don't want to refactor too much because that would make merge requests rather annoying.

Comment: Also what is the EAR?

Comment: EAR as in JavaEE Enterprise Archive: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html.
You can't run them with tomcat7, though. You could try with mvn jboss-as:run instead, then.